# how can i access to the JSON objects in crowd-checkbox of mturk with cloud templates?

Tags: javascript, mechanicalturk

I want to check if the right answer is checked among many checkboxes on Mturk Survey (to validate the participant reads the instruction).
I looked at the reference, but I am struggling to find how to access the boolean value of "checked"
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-crowd-checkbox.html

```
<div><crowd-checkbox name="Stop"> Red </div>
```

Let's say I want to access "Stop" value.

How should I call the value in the function?

Comment: it turns out the following code works well to me.
    var c = document.querySelector('crowd-form')
    var nodeList = c.querySelectorAll('crowd-checkbox')
    var nodeArray = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; ++i) {
        nodeArray[i] = nodeList[i];
    }