# Allow for multiple classes to be selected on Mturk's crowd-image-classifier

Tags: mechanicalturk

I'm using Mturk to create a dataset to train. a multiclass image classifier.

The documentation for the [crowd-image-classifier template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-crowd-image-classifier.html) doesn't show how to do this. Should I create a [crowd-checkbox](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-crowd-checkbox.html) for this? How? [This question and comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54596216/how-can-i-access-to-the-json-objects-in-crowd-checkbox-of-mturk-with-cloud-templ) suggest the use of javascript.

```html
    <script src="https://assets.crowd.aws/crowd-html-elements.js"></script>

    <!-- For the full list of available Crowd HTML Elements and their input/output documentation,
          please refer to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/sms-ui-template-reference.html -->

    <!-- You must include crowd-form so that your task submits answers to MTurk -->
    <crowd-form answer-format="flatten-objects">

        <!-- The crowd-classifier element will create a tool for the Worker to select the
               correct answer to your question.

              Your image file URLs will be substituted for the "image_url" variable below 
              when you publish a batch with a CSV input file containing multiple image file URLs.
              To preview the element with an example image, try setting the src attribute to
              "https://s3.amazonaws.com/cv-demo-images/one-bird.jpg" -->
        <crowd-image-classifier 
            src="${image_url}"
            categories="['Cat', 'Dog', 'Bird', 'None of the Above']"
            header="Choose the correct category"
            name="category">

           <!-- Use the short-instructions section for quick instructions that the Worker
                  will see while working on the task. Including some basic examples of 
                  good and bad answers here can help get good results. You can include 
                  any HTML here. -->
            <short-instructions>
                <p>Read the task carefully and inspect the image.</p>
                <p>Choose the appropriate label that best suits the image.</p>
            </short-instructions>

            <!-- Use the full-instructions section for more detailed instructions that the 
                  Worker can open while working on the task. Including more detailed 
                  instructions and additional examples of good and bad answers here can
                  help get good results. You can include any HTML here. -->
            <full-instructions header="Classification Instructions">
                <p>Read the task carefully and inspect the image.</p>
                <p>Choose the appropriate label that best suits the image.</p>
            </full-instructions>

        </crowd-image-classifier>
    </crowd-form>
```

---

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you are looking for. It is called classifier-multi-select instead of image-classifier

It's a template (with crowd code) you need to paste into the design layout of MTurk, otherwise the provided html code for image classification is by default single-label (single-class)

https://github.com/awsdocs/amazon-sagemaker-developer-guide/blob/master/doc_source/sms-ui-template-crowd-classifier-multi-select.md

or here an alternative one:

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-ground-truth-task-uis/blob/master/images/image-classification-multiselect.liquid.html

Comment: It's a template you need to paste into the design layout of MTurk, otherwise the provided html code for image classification is by default single-label (single-class)